# Populating Mongoose schema properties with models in external files

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate, odm

Im trying to [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) a property inside a Mongoose schema, which references a property in another external model/schema.

I can get the Mongoose population/referencing working when the two models/schemas and the query are all in the same file, but I have my architecture setup so the models are all in their own files within the */models* directory, and the */models/index.js* will return an object of models (obviously the *index.js* knows to exclude itself)

The problem I'm running into, is since the Schemas/Models are all in their own files, when I specify the model name as a reference, it doesn't work. I try to load that specific model itself inside the other model, and that also fails.

*FYI: Im fairly new to MongoDB and Mongoose, so the following code is very very rough, it's mostly me in the process of learning*

*Group Model*

```
// models/group.js
'use strict'

module.exports = Mongoose => {
    const Schema = Mongoose.Schema

    const modelSchema = new Schema({
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true
        }
    })

    return Mongoose.model( ModelUtils.getModelName(), modelSchema )
}
```

*Account Model*

```
// models/account.js
'use strict'

module.exports = Mongoose => {
    // I tried loading the specific model being referenced, but that doesn't work
    const Group = require('./group')( Mongoose )
    const Schema = Mongoose.Schema

    const modelSchema = new Schema({
        username: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        _groups: [{
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Group'
        }]
    })

    // Trying to create a static method that will just return a
    // queried username, with its associated groups
    modelSchema.statics.findByUsername = function( username, cb ) {
        return this
            .findOne({ username : new RegExp( username, 'i' ) })
            .populate('_groups').exec(cb)
    }

    return Mongoose.model( ModelUtils.getModelName(), modelSchema )
}
```

As you can see in the Account model, Im trying to reference the Group model as the *_groups* element, and then querying for an account while populating the associated groups inside the *modelSchema.statics.findByUsername* static method..

*Main Application File*

```
// app.js
const models = require('./models')( Mongoose )

models.Account.findByUsername('jdoe', ( err, result ) => {
    console.log('result',result)

    Mongoose.connection.close()
})
```

Comment: Why exactly are you `require`ing the group model in the account model? Looking at the given code, it does not seem necessary. What's the purpose of `ModelUtils`?

Comment: I actually have that commented out locally, it was throwing errors. I was **guessing** maybe the Accounts model needed it, since it was being referenced, but that was just a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not clear how the `ModelUtils.getModelName()` is implemented. I think the issue should be here, because it works well after I changing your codes as below

```
 // group.js
return Mongoose.model( 'Group', modelSchema );

 // account.js
return Mongoose.model( 'Account', modelSchema );

// app.js
const models = require('./models/account.js')( Mongoose );

models.findByUsername('jdoe', ( err, result ) => {
```

Comment: The `ModelUtils.getModelName()` just gets the name of the file, and converts it from `/models/account.js` to `Account`. It just returns a string.... how would hat be causing the error?

[Heres the code for it](http://pastebin.com/tLerkVi5)

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the `/models/index.js` which loads all of the models? Heres that file: http://pastebin.com/D0r8bPpS

Comment: +zangw, it seems to work when I replace `ModelUtils.getModelName()` with just a regular string... Any idea why that would be? That function just returns a string... I cant think of a reason why that would be the issue, but it obviously is